# subprocess pythontex wont work

Tags: python, latex, subprocess, pdflatex

This script creates an LaTeX version of ask.tex, using pythontex. The python code includes `subprocess`, and full python code `runme.py` is,

```
#Python 3.4.3
import sys
import os
import re
import subprocess
import shutil


subprocess.call(['pdflatex', 'Ask.tex'])
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'pythontex.py', 'Ask.tex'])
subprocess.call(['pdflatex', 'Ask.tex'])
```

and the LaTeX code `ask.tex` is,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=1.55in, right=1.55in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,caption}
\usepackage[norule]{footmisc}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\begin{pycode}[][]
import mysql.connector
conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='oilwell',host='localhost',database='sqlpush1')
mycursor=conn.cursor()
query=("SELECT oil from results WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2029-01-01'")
mycursor.execute(query)
data= mycursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    print("{}".format(row[0]))
mycursor.close()
conn.close()
\end{pycode}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{NET ENTITLEMENT FISH OIL MARKETS}}\\
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{AS OF DECEMBER 31, 2019}}\\\hline
    %\rowcolor{Cyan}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Country}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Company}}&Proved Cooked&Proved Uncooked&Total Proved\\
    %\rowcolor{Cyan}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&(T)&(T)&\cellcolor{blue!25}(T)\\\hline
    ChUAN& \pyc{print("{}".format(row[0]))} &51,574&31,202&82,776\\\hline
    IraW-West POINT &  & 9,656 &57,981&67,637\\\hline
     \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{KAZSLSKDE}}& PKKR& 32,129 &5,174& 37,304 \\\cline{2-5}
     \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&KOLKOL&9,718&3,447&13,165\\\cline{2-5}
     \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&PKPK&424&0&424\\\hline
     TOTAL CNNNO & & 103,501 & 97,804 & 201,306\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Pythontex need 3-steps to compile the files, first run `pdflatex`, then run 'pythontex file.py', and run `pdflatex` again.

I put both `runme.py`and `ask.tex` under the folder of pythontex, which has the `pythotex.py` file.

After I run `runme.py` in IDLE mode, pdflatex could be executed, and cmd prompt windows pop up and finish without problem. **But the problem is, I can not see `pythontex.py` running, and that lead to no change in output pdf file.**

I'm appreciated any comments and help on this problem. Thanks a lot.

**[Updates]**
I edited the python code into,

```
import sys
import os
import re
import subprocess
import shutil


subprocess.call(['pdflatex', 'Ask.tex'])
try:
    subprocess.call(['pythontex', 'Ask.tex'])
except:
    subprocess.call(['pythontex.py', 'Ask.tex'])
subprocess.call(['pdflatex', 'Ask.tex'])
```

Again, `pdflatex` could be executed, however, there is some error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cheng\Desktop\LaTeX Project\pythontex\runme2.py", line 10, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['pythontex', 'Ask.tex'])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cheng Zhang\Desktop\LaTeX Project\pythontex\runme2.py", line 12, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['pythontex.py', 'Ask.tex'])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

And that's new problem. **Core problem, pythontex won't run.**

Comment: have you tried passing the full paths?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, could you show me how?

Comment: Does `pdflatex` work from a cmd prompt? Also is `'Ask.tex'` in your cwd?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, 'pdflatex' is working in cmd prompt, I'm not sure what do you do mean by cwd?

Comment: current working directory

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, root folder, then a) ask.tex b)runme.py c)pythontex.py three files all under same folder, or cwd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found this way could be solve the problem perfectly.

```
#Python 3.4.3
import sys
import os
import re
import subprocess
import shutil


subprocess.call(['pdflatex', 'ask.tex'])
try:
    subprocess.call(['pythontex', 'ask.tex'], shell=True)
except:
    subprocess.call(['pythontex.py', 'ask.py'], shell=True)
subprocess.call(['pdflatex', 'ask.tex'])
```

The key part is add, `shell=True`, otherwise Python won't recognize the statement.